# Correct MultiChoice Values in LINQ to SharePoint Query

Tags: linq, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, enumeration, linq-to-sharepoint

I am using a LINQ to SharePoint query to return items from a SharePoint list.

```
var myOpenTasksQuery = from myTasks in tasks
                       where myTasks.TaskStatus != TaskStatus.Completed
                       select myTasks
```

However, the list I am querying, an OOTB Tasks list, there are a number of multi-choice fields (Status, Priority), which are translated into enumerations.  In my query results, a task item status is returned as "_2Normal", and not as "(2) Normal" as I would expect.  I see in the proxy file generated by SPMetal.exe that there is a ChoiceAttribute for the task status enumeration which contains the value I require:

```
public enum Priority : int {

    None = 0,

    Invalid = 1,

    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.ChoiceAttribute(Value="(1) High")]
    _1High = 2,

    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.ChoiceAttribute(Value="(2) Normal")]
    _2Normal = 4,

    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.ChoiceAttribute(Value="(3) Low")]
    _3Low = 8,
}
```

How can I modify the query above to return the correct value?

Thanks, MagicAndi.

Comment: Also, if someone reads this who has more than 1500 reputation, could you please add the new tag "linq-to-sharepoint"?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely the task item status is being returned as a value of type `Priority` - not a string at all. If you want to display that, I'd expect you to have to convert it into a string appropriately (possibly using some helper methods which take note of the attribute applied to some values).

Just calling `ToString()` on an enum value will return the name of the value if it has one, or a string representation of the number otherwise. It won't care about `ChoiceAttribute`. I suspect that's what's happening here.

Comment: Jon, apologies for the delay in answering, accepted as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try using this extension method to get the actual string value of your enum.

```
foreach (var o in  myOpenTasksQuery)
{
    Console.WriteLine(o.Priority.StringValueOf());
}



public static class Extensions
{
    public static string StringValueOf(this Enum value)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.ChoiceAttribute[] attributes =
            (Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.ChoiceAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(
            typeof(Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.ChoiceAttribute), false);
        if (attributes.Length > 0)
        {
            return attributes[0].Value;
        }
        else
        {
            return value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that querying a choicefield, as generated by SPMetal by default, will not be translated to CAML and thus your tasks-list will first be completely loaded to memory, and queried afterwards.

This, in short, means that as (and if) your tasks-list grows in time, performance of the query will drop equally.

I have, so far, not found a solution to it yet (struggling with it).